# Getting nearest gene from SNP data using SNP ID, CHR, and BP

Tags: gene, snp, gwas

I have data from a GWAS that provides me with the SNP, Chromosome, and base-pair. My data set has thousands of SNPs. What is the easiest way to find the nearest gene for each SNP using this information? My data looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What language are you using? There are some approaches listed here: https://www.biostars.org/p/111225/ , do any of those answers suit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want the nearest gene or the gene(s) that overlap the position? What if the nearest gene is a few megabases away, would you still want that?

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes that you have a terminal that runs linux commands and python, and that you can install and run bedtools.

**step 1:** convert your input spreadsheet to [BED format](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiN9KTU7sr9AhU3JjQIHWiHA5YQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgenome.ucsc.edu%2FFAQ%2FFAQformat.html&usg=AOvVaw1YBDwZ04GPxtn2N95WP6Lr).
There is probably an awk one liner that does this but something like this python script will do it based on csv input (assuming that your coordinates are 1-indexed):

```
# writes BED format to standard output, capture it in input_file.bed
# not actually run
with open("input_file.csv") as infile:
  for line in infile:
    fields = line.split(",")
    coord = int(fields[2])
    outline = f"chr{fields[0]}\t{coord - 1}\t{coord}\t{fields[1]}"
    print(outline)
```

**step 2:**
sort the BED.

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n input_file.bed > input_file.sorted.bed
```

**step 3:**
Get genome annotations. I am assuming that you are using the grch38 build of the human genome.

```
wget https://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/gencode/Gencode_human/release_43/gencode.v43.annotation.gff3.gz
```

**step 4:**
Get nearest gene for each snp.

```
bedtools closest -a input_file.sorted.bed -b gencode.v43.annotation.gff3.gz > input_annotated_with_genes.bed
```